# If statement issue, not adding values

Tags: java, conditional-statements

For the `if commercial` statement:

if I enter `1500` for `usage`, it prints out

```
Total amount due: 22.560.0
```

but it should be `22.5+60.0 (82.5)`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UtilityBill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // residential customer
        final double RES_RATE = 0.052;
        final double RES_FEE = 6;

        // commercial customer
        final int COM_LIMIT = 1000;
        final double COM_RATE = 0.045;
        final double COM_FEE = 60;

        // industrial customer
        final int IND_LIMIT = 5000;
        final int IND_LIMIT_2 = 1000;
        final int IND_LIMIT_3 = 3000;

        final double IND_RATE_BELOW = 0.028;
        final double IND_FEE_BELOW = 76;
        final double IND_RATE_ABOVE = 0.03;
        final double IND_FEE_ABOVE = 270;

        // user input
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the type of use ('R', 'C', or 'I'): ");
        char userType = kb.next().charAt(0);  // should be R, C, or I
        System.out.println("How much electricity do you use (in kwh)? ");
        double usage = kb.nextDouble();   // usage amount in kwh

        // if residential
        if (userType == 'R')
            System.out.println("Total amount due: " + (RES_RATE*usage)+RES_FEE);

        // if commercial
        if (userType == 'C')
            if (usage <= COM_LIMIT)
                System.out.println("Total amount due: " + COM_FEE);
            else
                System.out.println("Total amount due: " + ((usage-COM_LIMIT)*COM_RATE)+COM_FEE);

            // if industrial
        if (userType == 'I')
            if (usage <= IND_LIMIT)
                System.out.println("Total amount due: " + ((usage-IND_LIMIT_2)*IND_RATE_BELOW)+IND_FEE_BELOW);
            else
                System.out.println("Total amount due: " + ((usage-IND_LIMIT_3)*IND_RATE_ABOVE)+IND_FEE_ABOVE);

        kb.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the constants values?

Comment: Rest of the code please - where you define RES_RATE, RES_FEE etc. Nothing seems to be wrong in the code shown.

Comment: Hi, I just added the rest of the code!!

Comment: Your amounts are getting added as a string 22.560.0 is a addition of "22.5"+"60.0". You need to parse the value which you get from the user to similar datatype

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I am new to coding, could you explain a little more on how to change the values?

Comment: `double var= Double.parseDouble(str);`. Replace `str` with your value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple explanation to your issue. It's all about precedence of operators. Consider a simple code as :

```
int a = 6;
int b = 7;
System.out.println("Sum up : " + a + b);
```

While `"Sum up : "` is a String and `"+"` being the only overloaded operator in Java will is capable of concatenating number to String. 
Over here we have 2 `"+"` operator here, and `a + b` falls after the `"Sum up : "` + as already taken place, Its considering x and y as Strings too. An output will be :

```
Sum up : 67
```

Now consider this code :

```
int a = 6;
int b = 7;
System.out.println("Sum up : " + (a + b));
```

Over here the brackets `()` have higher precedence so first `(a+b)` and later printing the result as :

```
Sum up : 13
```

Coming back to your code :

```
System.out.println("Total amount due: " + ((usage-COM_LIMIT)*COM_RATE)+COM_FEE);
```

Now consider :

```
((usage-COM_LIMIT)*COM_RATE) -> a
COM_FEE -> b
```

The expression becomes as :

```
System.out.println("Total amount due: " + a + b);
```

Which is similar to my first code snippet.

So to get the desired result you need to get brackets added and convert to second example case :

```
System.out.println("Total amount due: " + (((usage-COM_LIMIT)*COM_RATE)+COM_FEE));
```

Let me know if you have any issue in understanding.